# Alcatel SR 7750 - Remove unused config

Tags: alcatel-lucent-7750

I have a lab SR (7750) which has not been cleaned up for many many years. As a result there is left over config in all places (empty lags, services without SAPs, configured ports with no link, etc). The configuration is ~48K lines ... Some of the config is being used and I do not want to wipe it.

Are there any commands to help me clean-up the box? For example, I am looking for:

- Resetting a port to factory defaults including cleaning up any services associated with that port
- Detecting services that although seem up they have no effect (like vpls without any SAPs or ports)
- Finding filters that are not associated with anything
- etc...

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resources.

Answer (score 1):

If the services are down then you could just delete the configuration and SAPs associated with them.

Comment: I have done it by hand now... however, its a lot more complex than SAPs. Local DHCP servers, routing protocol neighbours, any non-shut routing protocols, any imports/exports from grt, etc had to be removed and/or shut before being able to delete the service.